# How to style LikeButton in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a like button (using like_button library) that also has to show the number of likes next to it however my icon is stacked on top of the number of likes, how can I create some space between them?

```
Expanded(
                          child: LikeButton(
                            size: 15,
                            likeCount: 0,
                            likeBuilder: (bool like) {
                              return Icon(
                                Icons.thumb_up,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              );
                            },
                          ), //Text("Liked"),
                        ),
```

this is what I get:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either wrap your `Icon` with a `Padding` widget:

```
LikeButton(
    size: 30,
    likeCount: 0,
    likeBuilder: (bool like) {
      return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0)
          child: Icon(
              Icons.thumb_up,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
        );
    },
),
```

or use the `likeCountPadding` property already defined in the `LikeButton`:

```
LikeButton(
    size: 15,
    likeCount: 0,
    likeCountPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0)
    likeBuilder: (bool like) {
      return Icon(
        Icons.thumb_up,
        color: Colors.red,
      );
    },
),
```

Comment: LikeCountpadding worked and makes the code cleaner. Thanks.